# How to Send SMS on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am developing **Xamarin.Forms** project, iOS, Android and Windows Phone.

My app ask the user to enter text Message and Phone number then on submit, I need to send SMS to the phone number.

I prefer to have a single implementation for all platforms.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use this open source plugin **Xam.Plugins.Messaging**
https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins

This is the provided example (from https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/master/Messaging/Details.md ) :

```
// Make Phone Call
var phoneDialer = CrossMessaging.Current.PhoneDialer;
if (phoneDialer.CanMakePhoneCall) 
    phoneDialer.MakePhoneCall("+272193343499");

// Send Sms
var smsMessenger = CrossMessaging.Current.SmsMessenger;
if (smsMessenger.CanSendSms)
   smsMessenger.SendSms("+27213894839493", "Well hello there from Xam.Messaging.Plugin");

var emailMessenger = CrossMessaging.Current.EmailMessenger;
if (emailMessenger.CanSendEmail)
{
    // Send simple e-mail to single receiver without attachments, bcc, cc etc.
    emailMessenger.SendEmail("to.plugins@xamarin.com", "Xamarin Messaging Plugin", "Well hello there from Xam.Messaging.Plugin");

    // Alternatively use EmailBuilder fluent interface to construct more complex e-mail with multiple recipients, bcc, attachments etc. 
    var email = new EmailMessageBuilder()
      .To("to.plugins@xamarin.com")
      .Cc("cc.plugins@xamarin.com")
      .Bcc(new[] { "bcc1.plugins@xamarin.com", "bcc2.plugins@xamarin.com" })
      .Subject("Xamarin Messaging Plugin")
      .Body("Well hello there from Xam.Messaging.Plugin")
      .Build();

    emailMessenger.SendEmail(email);
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some code and add brief description that will make your answer more clear . Stackoverflow.com doest like URL . Thanks

Comment: thanks alot, this is is clearly more than previous one.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft now has this feature in their new all-encompasing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials NuGet package.

Comment: @lan Vink could you pleaes make your question have more details than link .thx